# Pip attribute error fromtimestamp

Tags: python, pip

I always get this error when I try to install a python module using pip (py -m pip install (whatever) )

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main as _main  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\userAppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\email\utils.py", line 30, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\datetime.py", line 10, in <module>
    date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(str(['positionTS']) / 1e3)
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'fromtimestamp'
```

I've tried several options from here to fix it but each results in the same error.  I am wondering if I need to uninstall then re-install, possibly with an older version.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks very similar to a problem I have seen (and answered already). Looks like you have either a module or a Python program that's names the same as a system module: `datetime.py` (I see `"C:\Users\user\Desktop\datetime.py"` in your stack trace).

There are many situations when this can lead to problems and should be avoided.

See here for another example of the same situation:

[ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'; 'tensorflow' is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51069945/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-contrib-tensorflow-is-not-a)

Comment: Right, there's an error i didn't know could be caused.  It reveals another error (can't find the file specified) that i'll have to do some digging into.